# How to play multiple jwplayer players one one page side by side

Tags: html, jwplayer, sizing

I'm trying to create a page where I have multiple streams of video coming in from the web.

Primary its news, Im making a page just to format the videos so they line up next to each other.

I wanted to have a total of 3 videos on the top section and another 3 below it so when it is in full screen mode, it will display 6 streams in one page and fill the screen.

When I try adding anything with margins, it does nothing but the videos are below one another.

I have included a sample of the coding I have done so far.

Any help would be great. I'm doing this for a Rescue group who wants to view news while they are working and to have a matrix of videos to see global happenings.

```
<pre>

head
<title>Incident Command System Global News</title> 
        body bgcolor="black"
     script data-cfasync="false" src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/SakQCEfSEeOHhRIxOQfUww.js"></script>
div id="videoA"></div>
div id="videoB"></div<br>
div id="videoC"></div>
div id="videoD"></div><br>

script>
    jwplayer("videoA").setup({ 
   "file": "http://peer3.savitar.tv/TruTV/myStream/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9MTEvNS8yMDE5IDE6NTg6MzIgQU0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT0zdCtTVWFMWnVhQ0kybkJUcU5KT2xRPT0mdmFsaWRtaW51dGVzPTM2MCZpZD0w",
  "aspectratio": "16:9",
  "width": "50%",
  "margin":  "2px 2px",
  "autostart": "true",
  "position": "inline-block",
  "padding-bottom": "24%",
  "mute": "false"
});

    jwplayer("videoB").setup({ 
   "file": "http://live.savitar.tv/AE/myStream/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9MTEvNS8yMDE5IDI6MTI6MzQgQU0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT1TL2Q2ZEd1VEhtWGpQSFNCdHNFaklnPT0mdmFsaWRtaW51dGVzPTM2MCZpZD0w",
  "aspectratio": "16:9",
  "width": "50%",
  "margin":  "2px 2px",
  "autostart": "true",
  "position": "inline-block",
  "padding-bottom": "24%",
  "mute": "false"
});

    jwplayer("videoC").setup({ 
   "file": "http://peer3.savitar.tv/FoxNews/myStream/playlist.m3u8?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9MTEvNS8yMDE5IDI6MzM6MzMgQU0maGFzaF92YWx1ZT1pdTg4NE1qeHY1TFBWdC9uMU9XWk1RPT0mdmFsaWRtaW51dGVzPTM2MCZpZD0w",
  "aspectratio": "16:9",
  "width": "50%",
  "margin":  "2px 2px",
  "autostart": "true",
  "position": "inline-block",
  "padding-bottom": "24%",
  "mute": "false"
});

</script>
</pre>
```